# What would happen if a person were magnetized?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I know this is an out there kind of question, but I’ve been redirected to this SE from two other SEs. What I want to know is if a person were to hypothetically become magnetic, would everything diamagnetic be repelled away from their body? So for instance, if they ever tried to grab a glass of water, it would be pushed away from their hand moving forward. Likewise if they tried reaching for a block of wood or wearing clothes made out of repulsive fabric, it wouldn’t be able to make physical contact. I would also like to know what happens if this person of one magnetic charge is standing in a room made out of a material with the opposite magnetic charge (like South Pole and North Pole). Would the walls bend and move back as the person approaches them, or would the person be unable to move towards the walls and be repelled by them instead?

In other words, if you have a wall made out of the south poles of four giant bar magnets, and then drop an equally large magnet into the space between the walls by its north pole first, would the walls bend back and/or collapse, or would the other magnet be unable to go inside the walls?

Comment: Is there a reason you are asking about people becoming magnetic? Why not ask about how a magnet behaves? I understand there are rumors about COVID vaccines making people magnetic, but it does not happen. In general, people are no more magnetic than a block of wood.

Comment: I am asking for a story I am writing about a person who gets magnetized. It’s fiction, but I would prefer for it to have some realism

Comment: Then magnetic people is your first problem with realism. But if you want to suppose that and take if from there, just expect that glasses of water would behave like they do around real magnets. Diamagnetism and paramagnetism are much smaller forces than ferromagnetism. You wouldn't notice them.